# Convert a 18 character string to and int

Tags: string, ms-access, integer

How to convert 18 character string to int in microsoft access database

e.g "999999999999999999"

Comment: you can convert into number in ms access data base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. An int is too small to hold a number like that.

You can convert it to the Decimal data type:

```
cdec('999999999999999999')
```

Comment: this is the erroe it gives me " The expression you entered has a function containing the wrong number of arguments."

Comment: @bsanneh: The CDec function is supported in VBA code in Access, but not in queries. Se this for a way to add support in queries: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/225931

Comment: It's supported in queries run *within* Access. I'd think it would also be supported via ODBC/OLEDB, but since I never use Jet/ACE via those interfaces, I'm not sure.

Comment: You have to use double quotes for it to work: `CDec("999999999999999999")`

Comment: @David need to do a modulo calculation so i have to convert it to an integer to be able to do that

Comment: You'll have to scale it down, then.